# Error: No response from Gunicorn master within 120 seconds . Shutting down webserver. Airflow-Webserver Service won't start

Tags: airflow, devops, prometheus, airflow-scheduler, statsd

I want to monitor my airflow worker logs with the help of Prometheus.
So I looked up on the internet and found statsd-exporter can help me.
But, when I added the required configuration of statsd-exporter in Airflow.cfg , Service wont start.

Airflow.cfg file

```
[scheduler]
statsd_on = True
statsd_host = xxx.xxx.x.xxx
statsd_port = 9125
statsd_prefix = airflow
```

When I restart The service after adding these lines in Airflow.cfg , it doesnt restart and throws above error in logs.

When I remove these lines , It starts perfectly.

I installed statsd and statsd-exporter via pip.
Also can anyone suggest any better way this can be done.

Comment: Have you installed all the airflow dependencies ? https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/metrics.html . please take a look.

Comment: does this work without statsd configuration changes ?

Comment: @hopeIsTheonlyWeapon yes

Comment: @hopeIsTheonlyWeapon yes all dependencies are installed.

Comment: Can you kindly put the complete stack trace also provide more details about the environment where you are running airflow

Comment: @hopeIsTheonlyWeapon yes , I am running airflow in Centos 7 . This is the complete trace i get when i see the logs.